# How is Student's t-distribution related with this similarity/probability equation between data points?

Tags: probability, clustering, distance, t-distribution, tsne

In the t-SNE paper "[Visualizing Data using t-SNE](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf)" and a Deep Embedded Clustering (DEC) approach "[Unsupervised Deep Embedding for Clustering Analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06335.pdf)", they both use the Student t-distribution to quantify the probability/similarity/distance between two data points:

[image]

[image]

### **But how is this `q` related to the [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) shown below?**

I'm not quite familiar with the t distribution. When I check the PDF of the t distribution from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) (in the following), I could not see the link between them. 
[image]

Comment: The paper mentions it's using the t-distribution with one degree of freedom which is equal to a cauchy distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Special_cases, it's then using this to calculate the joint probability distribution for $q_{ij}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $\nu=1$ the PDF becomes

$$f(t)\propto C \cdot (1+t^2)^{-1}$$

With a scaling term $C=\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\Gamma\left(\tfrac12\right)}$ independent of t that will eventually cancel out when normalizing the values to a sum of 1.

Comment: So they compute t-distribution probability from Squared Euclidean distance between a data point and a centroid, then the t-distribution probabilities are normalized across all clusters to become the `q` probabilities. I see. Thank you!

Comment: Neighbors, not clusters.